# Two click functions, affecting the same div, the first work but second not - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button which opens a popup when clicked, and in this popup there is a close button to close the popup but that close button is not working!

Here is my code:

```js
var fromToDate = document.getElementById('from-to-date');
var openFromToDate = document.getElementById('open-from-to-date');
var closeFromToDate = document.getElementById('close-from-to-date');
openFromToDate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fromToDate.classList.remove('dis-none');
});
closeFromToDate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fromToDate.classList.add('dis-none');
});
```

```css
.dis-none {
  display: none;
}

/* To make the button visible here */
.fa-times::after {
  content: 'X';
}
```

```html
<li id="open-from-to-date">
  <span class="custom-span-style warning-bk date-span">
    From: 2022-09-16 To: 2022-09-18
  </span>
  <div class="from-to-date dis-none" id="from-to-date">
    <div class="from-to-date-wrapper">
      <div class="close-from-to-date" id="close-from-to-date">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: The problem is event bubbling; when you click on your close button, the click handler for that one fires, and adds the class. Then the event bubbles up to the `li` element, the click handler for that one fires - and removes the class again. You either need to stop the click event on the "close" element from bubbling up, or check inside the `li` click handler, that the event target is not the close element (or one of its descendants.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you click the close button, two listeners fire: First, the close button listener fires and adds `dis-none`, but then the open "button" listener also fires and removes `dis-none` again. This is because the close button is *contained* within the open "button", so any click on the close button also constitutes a click on the open "button" at the same time.

You can easily check this by adding `console.log` statements to the two listeners.

The solution is therefore to not let the event [bubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture) up to any listeners on parent elements once you handled it on the close button itself, which can be done using [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation):

```js
var fromToDate = document.getElementById('from-to-date');
var openFromToDate = document.getElementById('open-from-to-date');
var closeFromToDate = document.getElementById('close-from-to-date');
openFromToDate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fromToDate.classList.remove('dis-none');
});
closeFromToDate.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  fromToDate.classList.add('dis-none');
  e.stopPropagation(); // <---- THIS
});
```

```css
.dis-none {
  display: none;
}

/* To make the button visible here */
.fa-times::after {
  content: 'X';
}
```

```html
<li id="open-from-to-date">
  <span class="custom-span-style warning-bk date-span">
    From: 2022-09-16 To: 2022-09-18
  </span>
  <div class="from-to-date dis-none" id="from-to-date">
    <div class="from-to-date-wrapper">
      <div class="close-from-to-date" id="close-from-to-date">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

(Note: I also added the event argument `e` to the listener function so that we could call `stopPropgation` on it.)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is when you're clicking on the "closer" you are also clicking on the "opener" as well, say not? See the code below.

```js
var fromToDate = document.getElementById('from-to-date');
var openFromToDate = document.getElementById('open-from-to-date');
var closeFromToDate = document.getElementById('close-from-to-date');
openFromToDate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fromToDate.classList.remove('dis-none');
  console.log("I opened");
});
closeFromToDate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fromToDate.classList.add('dis-none');
  console.log("I closed");
});
```

```css
.dis-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li id="open-from-to-date">
  <span class="custom-span-style warning-bk date-span">From: 2022-09-16 To: 2022-09-18</span>
  <div class="from-to-date dis-none" id="from-to-date">
    <div class="from-to-date-wrapper">
      <div class="close-from-to-date" id="close-from-to-date">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Close!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Now you have two ways to correct this:

#### window.setTimeout

```js
var fromToDate = document.getElementById('from-to-date');
var openFromToDate = document.getElementById('open-from-to-date');
var closeFromToDate = document.getElementById('close-from-to-date');
openFromToDate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fromToDate.classList.remove('dis-none');
});
closeFromToDate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    fromToDate.classList.add('dis-none');
  }, 2);
});
```

```css
.dis-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li id="open-from-to-date">
  <span class="custom-span-style warning-bk date-span">From: 2022-09-16 To: 2022-09-18</span>
  <div class="from-to-date dis-none" id="from-to-date">
    <div class="from-to-date-wrapper">
      <div class="close-from-to-date" id="close-from-to-date">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Close!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

In this method, the removing method runs 2ms later which means two lines of JS code later.

#### Capture parameter of addEventListener which usually is overseen

#### RECOMMENDED

See this example:

```js
var fromToDate = document.getElementById('from-to-date');
var openFromToDate = document.getElementById('open-from-to-date');
var closeFromToDate = document.getElementById('close-from-to-date');
openFromToDate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fromToDate.classList.remove('dis-none');
  console.log("I'm opened");
}, true); //Magic happens here
closeFromToDate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fromToDate.classList.add('dis-none');
  console.log("I'm closed");
});
```

```css
.dis-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li id="open-from-to-date">
  <span class="custom-span-style warning-bk date-span">From: 2022-09-16 To: 2022-09-18</span>
  <div class="from-to-date dis-none" id="from-to-date">
    <div class="from-to-date-wrapper">
      <div class="close-from-to-date" id="close-from-to-date">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Close!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

In this example, the capturing method of the opening event is set to true which means, the event listening is in the capturing phase instead of the bubbling phase which is the default.

In the capturing phase, the outmost event listener runs first so the opening event is captured first and closing event, next.

##### For more information, see [here](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).

Comment: Well-presented answer, but unfortunately both of the options you offered are bad practice and kinda "circumvent" the problem instead of solving it, as all you do is ensuring the opener fires before the closer. In my opinion, the only logically "direct" way would be to not even have the opener listener fire at all in case the closer was clicked, which can be achieved using `stopPropagation` as explained in my answer.

Comment: Have a good day; I'm not as knowledgeable as you are, @CherryDT that's why I represented what I knew but I know that I have a long way to become a good programmer and I too prefer your answer as I upvoted it

Comment: Anyway, keep 'em coming, don't get discouraged from sharing your knowledge nonetheless. You are presenting the answer in a great way (even if the solution it shows may not be the best). There are many answers in SO that contain some correct solution but are presented badly, for instance with just a blob of code and no explanation, but your answer is well-written and well-formatted, so kudos for that.

Comment: That means a lot coming from you; Thanks! And I'm here to help however I could and I'm sure helping here helps me well; for instance, today I learned something new, "stopPropagation".